# in CAKEPHP needs to add index.php with root url , example.com/index.php

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp-2.0

I have hosted my project in cakephp to server. I needs to give the url conia.net/index.php to load at first time. Next time onwards it is enough to give  conia.net(if it is in the same browser). What should i do to overcome this ?

Comment: That depends on wether mod_rewrite is enabled or not.

Comment: Here is my domain www.conia.net. if we take www.conia.net/index.php , the site will load. But www.conia.net is not loading. But once we take www.conia.net/index.php, in the same browser, next time onwards www.conia.net will work..